# Generate all combinations of elements between arrays

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have multiple arrays that contain multiple elememts, for example:

```
$array1 = (1,2)
$array2 = (3,4)
```

I need to generate all possible combinations for elements of arrays. For given example, the output should be:

```
1_3, 1_4, 2_3, 2_4
```

However, the issue is that both number of arrays and amount of elements in each one can be different. So we can also take something like that:

```
$array1 = (1,2,3,4) 
$array2 = (5,6,7) 
$array3 = (8,9,10,11,12)
```

and output should look like that:

```
1_5_8, 1_5_9, 1_5_10 etc. until 4_7_12.
```

How do I implement something like that? I know that I should use foreach loop, but I have no idea what to do if amount of "foreaches" can be different every time I execute algorithm.

Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: get it working for two arrays, then use the new array made from two arrays as one half of the next pair.

Comment: If you don't know anything about the arrays then it seems to me like an xy problem. Are you sure this is really needed? Can you go back a few steps an explain why this is needed and for what?

Comment: It's hard to explain... I have a product, arrays are options, and their values are variants (for example, product is T-shirt, we have option Color, and variants Blue, Black, Red). I have a store, and I want to generate every possible combination of product. That's why I i have unknown number of options and values whenever I execute algorithm - every product is different.

Comment: See similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111805/multidimensional-array-probability/55120178#55120178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 


$array1 = [1,2,3,4];
$array2 = [5,6,7];
$array3 = [8,9,10,11,12];

$collection = [$array1,$array2,$array3];

$result = $collection[0];
array_shift($collection);
foreach($collection as $each_array){
    $temp = [];
        foreach($result as $each_sub_result){
            foreach($each_array as $each_item){
                $temp[] = $each_sub_result."_".$each_item;
            }
        }    
    $result = $temp;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Algorithm:**

- We collect all arrays in our `$collection` variable.
- Now, we loop over all elements of our `$collection` variable where each individual item is an array.
- I have done an [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) since we are assigning first element of `$collection` to `$result`(so we don't want to iterate over them again).
- We maintain `$temp` to store temporary results. Note that we use `$result` also to store temporary results, so that we can iterate over it and get new temporary results. By **temporary**, I mean **building** the final array. For example: It starts with `1`, then `1_5` and then finally `1_5_8`.
- After the looping completes, we will have our final answer in `$result`.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(4,5,6);
foreach ($array1 as $a1){
    foreach ($array2 as $a2){
       echo $a1 . '_' . $a2 . ', ';
    }
}
```

You can expand it like you wish.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how many arrays I will have. It may be 2, it may be 3, it may be 68. I know how foreach inside foreach works, but it's viable only if number of arrays is constant.

Answer (score -1):

I'm good in JS so that's why I did the algo in JS, you can try to do this in PHP,,no much difficult. You just have to pass in all the array is the function and the rest should be done by itself. Let me know if any confusions.

```
    var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
    var arr2 = [4, 5];
    var arr3 = [6, 7, 8];

    var numberOfArrays = -1;

    function processArrays(concatWith = [], allArrays) {
        const duplicateArray = [...allArrays];
        for (var i = 0; i < allArrays.length; i++) {
            const currentArray = duplicateArray.splice(0, 1);
            currentArray[0].forEach(function (value) {
                concatWith.push(value);
                processArrays(concatWith, duplicateArray);
                if (concatWith.length === numberOfArrays) {
                    console.log(concatWith.join('_'));
                }
                concatWith.pop();
            });
        }
    }

    function makeCombinations(arrayOfAllArrays = []) {

        numberOfArrays = arrayOfAllArrays.length;
        processArrays([], arrayOfAllArrays);
    }


    makeCombinations([arr1, arr2, arr3]);
```